# Why does this simple two line python web scraping code execute correctly in python interpreters but not on my PC?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2, cloudflare

```py
import urllib2
hdr={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'}
print urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://mobile.lowvig.ag/sports', headers=hdr)).read()
```

This two line program prints the correct html code when I run it from these two online interpreters:
https://repl.it/languages/python
https://paiza.io/en/languages/python

However, when I run it from my home PC, it prints what looks to be a cloudflare warning page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->




</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> mobile.lowvig.ag</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
        <div class="cf-wrapper">
          <div class="cf-columns two">
            <div class="cf-column">

              <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
                <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="b3df19c7958863448f72e934c06ae7332861f030-1564882975-1800-AcBCDHplwdTaCzOhBkp56Ja0sk/FSnXB3lJxmJpKdOTH0MYNevcFL2u/8NelatBwLBq+AfsceRViMsHQs7gnTUCvyRKSpGh4IizRs3BPQflkFl9uaScZ4CoP1yZCKYWVWrFDkwELhwE6KPGUci0e6XT1ph465Mzcryl6xtId0S0U"></input>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="500cd664e845b615" async data-sitekey="6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0"></script>
  <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
  <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
    <div><div style="width: 302px">
      <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 300px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
    </div></div>
  </noscript>
</form>


              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-column">
              <div class="cf-screenshot-container">

                <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.columns -->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>

            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>


            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>

            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>

            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_privacy_pass">Another way to prevent getting this page in the future is to use Privacy Pass. Check out the browser extension in the <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-pass/ajhmfdgkijocedmfjonnpjfojldioehi">Chrome Store</a>.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
  <p>
    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong><snip></strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: <snip></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to figure out how these environments are accessing this page differently than my home PC, so that I can successfully scrape this website.

Update: In response to the two submitted answers:
The following code routes the request through a proxy (had to switch from urllib2 to requests), and brings up the same cloudflare page (with the proxy IP correctly shown as 'your ip' at the bottom):

```py
import requests
hdr={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'}
proxyDict={'https': 'https://user:pass@ip:port'}
print requests.get('https://mobile.lowvig.ag/sports', headers=hdr, proxies=proxyDict).content
```

This makes me think there may be something specific to my environment (other than my IP) that's triggering the issue. Also, I can view the website with no issues from my home IP in a normal browser.

Comment: The web server may want to prevent requests from scripts coming from unrecognised IPs.

Comment: This website has nothing to do with coding - so there's virtually no chance the requests coming from the IP addresses linked to the interpreters is the answer.

Comment: Cloudflare is the CDN. Their algorithm decided that your traffic is not legit, and the DDOS mitigation kicked in.

Comment: While I tend to agree - I'm left wondering why I'm able to replicate the cloudflare warning on a fresh machine/ip running this two line script (but it still works from interpreters)

Answer (score 1):

The site owner `lowvig.ag` has decided to captcha your IP address, AS number, country, or user-agent using Cloudflare, possibly to protect the site from bots.

If you believe that you should be exempted from this, you may want to contact the site owner to whitelist your IP address.

See https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203366080-Why-do-I-see-a-captcha-or-challenge-page-Attention-Required-trying-to-visit-a-site-protected-by-Cloudflare-as-a-site-visitor-

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code (based on Python 2.7), it worked from my PC. My IP is not blacklisted.

I created a similar code using Python 3.7. It worked too.

```
import urllib.request

hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    }

req = urllib.request.Request(
    'https://mobile.lowvig.ag/sports', 
    headers=hdr
    )

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Can you try the python 2.7 code from my update (using requests instead of urllib2) and tell me if it works for you? I tried running it from a completely different PC/IP combo and got the same cloudflare page (but the code works from the repl interpreter).

Comment: I analyzed  the issue a bit, it seems that many websites now is protected with Cloudflare from bot scripts.  Perhaps you could try https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape